# Unexpected Token error in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm completely beginner at react native development. I just followed code from a youtube video to perform basic routing. But it gave me some errors.

My Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Navigator } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './Pages/Splash';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={{
            id:'Splash'
          }}
          renderScene={
            this.initializeScenes
          }
          />
    );
  }
  initializeScenes(route,navigator){
    _navigator = navigator;
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'Splash':
        return(
          <Splash navigator={navigator}, title="Splash"/>
        )
        break;
      default:

    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

It gave me Unexpected Token error in the `<Splash navigator={navigator}, title="Splash"/>` line.

Comment: You have an extra comma on that line

Comment: Oh thank you so much @bennygenel. Now It's showing Navigator is deprecated error. I guess i have to follow an updated tutorial.

Comment: Check out the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) about navigation in React Native